# Using SSIS package to zip all the txt files and move to related folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Could someone provide the best solution to implement below task.   Thanks

1. Zip all the text file in one central folder (separate individual zip file)
2. Move all the zipped files to archived directory folder based on different file type.

Comment: How are you attempting to zip the files? Do you have a third party product installed, like 7-zip? Are you attempting to do this using the native Windows compression utility? Are you writing custom .NET code to perform the compression?

Comment: Yes, I do have 7-zip installed. I prefer to have SSIS package to do this task. Windows compression also fine.